# Options for entering parent-child data

Tags: child-to-parent

At the risk of having this question tagged as too general...

We are implementing SF in our organisation.  There are several instances of parent-child relationships, for example, entering a student's details and then the student's dependents.  Or, another example, creating a travel request for a family and then selecting each of the passenger names (parents and children).  In terms of creating new records, I don't see any way to do create parent child records simultaneously in the vanilla SF interface.  Is my only option for this Visual Force (or Lightning) pages?  Does an app exist for this?  I see lots of form apps, but they all seem to be for Web to SF, rather than running natively in SF.

Comment: There's no out of the box way to do this unless as you have already figured out that this needs to be a customization.

Comment: As far as I know, the only place Salesforce *sort of* does this is Opportunity Products on new Opportunities. In general, you're going to need to add the parent record first, save it, and then add associated line items.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm really amazed that this is not out-of-the box functionality.  Seems pretty basic

Comment: Check the AppExchange.  I think GridBuddy might be able to do parent plus multiple-child record entry on a single screen.

Answer (score 0):

There couple of scenarios I know where parent child records are created.

Lead conversion process where Account, contact, opportunity with Opportunity contact role are created.

Creation of Quote from Opportunity where Quote with Quote Line items are created.

Same principle applies to Order and Order Products.

Creation of case and associating with EntitlementId generates CaseMilestones.